# changing class of a span

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have two divs as follows and I want to change the class name of span s1 from div top2. But the following code is not working. How can I do that?

```
$('#top1 #s1 span.myclass-old').toggleClass('myclass-new');
```

```
<div id="top1">
   <span id="s1" class="myclass">a</span>
   <span id="s2" class="myclass">b</span>
</div>

<div id="top2">
   <span id="s1" class="myclass-old">a</span>
   <span id="s2" class="myclass">b</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You have multiple `id`s that are the same. Make sure you understand how the `id` attribute works, as that is causing your error.

Comment: Yes its happening because of repetition of same id

Comment: No, what you are doing wrong is, it is looking for a `span.myclass-old` inside `#s1` (because there is a space between those two in your code). This should be changed to `span#s1.myclass-old`. Also note that you CANNOT use the same id more than once in a single web page.

Comment: In fact there is one s1. But the div is draggable and I change the place of span. So I have to specify which div belongs to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wanna change your class from 'class-old' to 'class-new' try this code:

```
$('#top1 #s1.myclass-old').removeClass('myclass-old').addClass('myclass-new');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this `$('#top1 #s1').attr('class', 'myclass-new');​​`

http://jsfiddle.net/blackpla9ue/tBLFt/

Using toggleClass would only result in adding/removing `myclass-new` to your span while having the existing `myclass`.

Answer (score 0):

```
('#top1 > #s1').toggleClass('myclass-new');
```

[child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Your selector  `$('#top1 #s1 span.myclass-old').toggleClass('myclass-new');` will search for a span with id 's1' and then will search for ts children span with the class "myclass-old". In this case you have multiple same id's so you should use the following selector

`$('#top2 span.myclass-old').toggleClass('myclass-new');` or `$('#top1 span.myclass-old').toggleClass('myclass-new');`

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong,
try

```
$('#top1 #s1.myclass-old').toggleClass('myclass-new');
```

I suggest you change the ID of spans, as ID are used to be unique in the document, you might end up with messy code