# How do I change a span's class in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `ul` element with items in it like below and I want to change out the `span` element's class between `'glyphicon-ok greenstatus'` and `'glyphicon-remove redstatus'`.

Here is my HTML and JS where I want to change the `li` `id="overviewlink"` span class based on the condition returning from my post.

```js
$.post(url, {
    id: id,
    summary: summary,
    complete: completed
  }, function(response) {
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(response);

    if (jsonObj.Completed == 'complete') {
      // change span class in overview to 'glyphicon-ok greenstatus'
    } else {
      // change span class in overview to 'glyphicon-remove redstatus'
    }

    if (jsonObj.StepsToList == '0') {
      //change to enum drop down
    } else {
      // change enum drop down to message showing number of steps
    }
    $("#successmessage").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert("error");
  });
```

```html
<ul id="managelinks" class="nav nav-stacked">
  <li id="overviewlink">
    <a href="#overviewlink">Overview
                    @if (Model.Overview.Completed == ListingComplete.Complete)
                    {
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok greenstatus" aria-hidden="false"></span>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove redstatus" aria-hidden="false"></span>
                    }
                </a>
  </li>
  <li id="detailslink">
    <a href="#detailslink">Details 
                    @if (Model.Details.Completed == ListingComplete.Complete)
                    {
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok greenstatus" aria-hidden="false"></span>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove redstatus" aria-hidden="false"></span>
                    }
                </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [changing class of a span](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529700/changing-class-of-a-span)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery:

- [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)
- [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)
- [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Full documentation: http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) to do this:

```
$.post(url, {
    id: id,
    summary: summary,
    complete: completed
  }, function(response) {
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(response);

    if (jsonObj.Completed == 'complete') {
      // change span class in overview to 'glyphicon-ok greenstatus'
      $("#overviewlink span.glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-ok");
      $("#overviewlink span.glyphicon").addClass("greenstatus");
      $("#overviewlink span.glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-remove");
      $("#overviewlink span.glyphicon").removeClass("redstatus");
    } else {
      // change span class in overview to 'glyphicon-remove redstatus'
      $("#overviewlink span.glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-remove");
      $("#overviewlink span.glyphicon").addClass("redstatus");
      $("#overviewlink span.glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-ok");
      $("#overviewlink span.glyphicon").removeClass("greenstatus");
    }

    if (jsonObj.StepsToList == '0') {
      //change to enum drop down
    } else {
      // change enum drop down to message showing number of steps
    }
    $("#successmessage").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert("error");
  });
```

Comment: FYI, jQuery supports daisy chaining methods, and multiple classes can be passed to addClass / removeClass.

Comment: doesn' t this add and remove classes from the <li>, not the span? I added an id to the span named '"overviewspan' and I tried addclass and removeclass on these id's but it doesn't change in the browser. Maybe I have to do something else??